# Ubuntu 16.10 wont suspend

Tags: suspend, 16.10

I have ubuntu 16.10 with kernel 4.9.0-040900-generic with NVIDIA 367.57 for my G940M. When the lid is closed the computer suspend but the led is always on and I can not wake it up only after pressing the shutdown button and launching it again. is there any solution and thank you.

Comment: Try to install 4.8 Kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` for the problematic device in my case "XHC0     S4    *disabled"